# не работает fistp

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, fpu

при попытке использовать команду `fistp` вовремя компиляции выдаёт ошибку

> error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

в чём может быть проблема?

```
push 25
push 0

finit
fild qword [rsp+8]
fsqrt
fistp qword rsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Как видно из [описания](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdfpu/FISTP) команды `fistp`, она работает только с памятью, но не с регистрами. так что то, что вы написали, не сработает.

```
fistp qword ptr [esp]
```

Что-то вроде этого нужно... Если, конечно, это то, что вам нужно :)

Да и в `fild`, вообще-то, надо указать так же - типа

```
fild qword ptr [esp+8]
```

Впрочем, допускаю, что в разных ассемблерах может быть чуточку по-разному...

Comment: насм не понимает `ptr`. попробовал выделить буфер `buffer resb 8` `fistp qword buffer` но не помогло.